# editing navigation bar once for all pages

Tags: html, css, navbar, navigationbar

I am sure there must be an easy solution for this. I have started maintaining a website which is well-established. I need to add a new tab in the Navigation bar, which I did. However, I have to go through all the HTML pages in the website to reflect that edit.

Is there any other effective way, I can make the edit at one place and it gets reflected throughout. From what I have gathered, the site has multiple folders, and each respective index.html page as the HTML code for navigation bar. It is not importing or downloading it from some main source.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Any respectable IDE will have a global replace feature, which IDE are you using.

Comment: So far, I was using a text editor. But now, I am experimenting with Dreamweaver MX 2004, which I had used long time back

Comment: If you're new to the project are you sure the site is not the result of using a [static site generator](https://www.staticgen.com/) or some kind of build script / tool? Unless the site is over a decade old I'm surprised that it's a load of duplicated HTML.

Comment: You don't need Dreamweaver for that simple task. For example, you can you use Sublime Text (Ctrl+Shift+F) or Adobe Brackets (Ctrl+Shift+F or Ctrl+Shift+H). It is not a question for StackOverflow - it just a basic skills of using your software. If you prefer another text editor, just search in Google - **<Name of your editor> find and replace in all files**. I suggest you delete this question, because it's an off topic.

Comment: Okay, I shall delete the question if you feel so. I was just wondering if there was a 'learning'/effective technique behind doing it. Instead of "find-replace-all" which certainly saves times, and gets the job done, but does not add anything to my knowledge. Furthermore, I would like to learn this also because I suspect I would need to do this for multiple new edits, and thereby would avoid doing "find-replace all" everytime. Thanks for your input about Sublime though!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using PHP or anything like that you could write it once and with HTML5 they have imports.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-html-imports

Answer (score 0):

The **easiest** way when I deal with webpages like this is to convert all index.html to php (merely changing the file type). Copy out the navbar codes into a file, say "navbar.php". Then in every single index.php where the navbar should be, replace it with

```
<?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>
```

Add to "navbar.php" any additional folder paths that you may have.